# How to redirect to another handler in web.py from a POST method

Tags: python, redirect, http-post, web.py, string-substitution

The project is a simple web crawler and and search engine. The "Index" handler has a form for entering the domain to search and the term to find. I would like the POST method to redirect to the "LuckySearch" handler, which searches for the regex term.

I've tried using web.redirect() and web.seeother(), but it seems that these functions do not support string substitution. How else can I solve this problem?

```
class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        form = searchform()
        return render.formtest(form)

    def POST(self):
        form = searchform()
        if not form.validates():
            return render.formtest(form)
        else:
            word = form['word'].get_value()
            print "You are searching %s for the word %s" % (form['site'].get_value(), word)
            raise web.redirect('/%s') % word

class LuckySearch(object):
    def GET(self, query):
        query = str(query)
        lucky = lucky_search(corpus, query)
        ordered = str(pretty_ordered_search(corpus, query))
        if not lucky:
            return "I couldn't find that word anywhere! Try google.com instead."
        else:
            return "The best page is: " + lucky + "\n" + "but you might also try:" + "\n" + ordered

class About(object):
    def GET(self):
        return "This is my first search engine! It only runs on my local machine, though."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    corpus = crawl_web('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Sunday', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Sunday')
    app = web.application(('/', 'Index', '/about', 'About', '/(.*)', 'LuckySearch'), globals())
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line

```
raise web.redirect('/%s') % word
```

should be changed to

```
raise web.seeother('/%s' % word)
```

1. You have to use `%` on string, not `web.redirect` result.
2. I think `web.seeother` should be used instead of `web.redirect`, because the latter returns `301 Moved Permanently` redirect and I don't think you need permanent redirect here.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the tip on web.redirect vs. web.seeother.